# System.Web.Razor vs System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, configuration

What exactly is each of these assemblies used for? I just noticed that ASP.NET project seems to be working absolutely fine, when reference to System.Web.Razor is **deleted**.

As it seems not mandatory for application to function, is it safe to remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both assemblies are part of the Razor implementation. `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` has a reference to `System.Web.Razor`. You have removed it as reference from your project but your application only works because this assembly is in the GAC. Otherwise it wouldn't. So both are actually required to be present at runtime.

Comment: Should I understand it that I should reference System.Web.WebPages.Razor not System.Web.Razor in the project and in the package.config and webconfig?